# No. of 5-digit monotonic numbers

Tags: combinatorics

The monotonic number is made of digits 1, 2, …, 9, such that each subsequent number equal to or greater than the previous number. Examples: 11119, 12369, 18999 etc.

<strike>I understand that I can isolate the first and last digit, leaving me with 3 numbers, e.g. 117, 223, 789 etc.</strike>

The 1st digit can be 1-9, there are 9 cases. And the 2nd digit varies depending on the 1st one, and so does the 3rd digit.

My visualisation:

Case '1' = 9 cases for middle digit -> branches out to 9 cases for third digit

Case '2' = 8 cases for middle digit -> branches out to 8 cases for third digit
...
...

This is where I'm stuck...

Edit: actually the five-digit numbers don't have to start with 1 and end with 9. My bad. I don't even seem to be comprehending my own homework question properly.

Comment: Stars and bars works :)

Comment: https://ideone.com/dpXD6X 1287.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not necessarily an answer, because I am not sure if it is true, but see if this helps. Suppose we have some sort of counter $x$ which starts at $1$, and whenever I write $m$, I want you to increment $x$ by $1$. Now when I want  to print out $x$, I will write $N$. This might be a little confusing, so let me give you an example.

$nnnMnMnMMnnMn$

In this case, I print out $n$ 3 times, so the first $M$ has a value of $4$. The second $M$ has a value of 5, then $6$, then $6$, then $8$. So the above string is $45668$. Could this be a hint?

$MnnnnnnnnMMMM$ then would be 19999. So this question really becomes into how many ways we can rearrange the $n$'s and $M$'s. Your answer is, I am guessing, $\frac{13!}{8!5!}$

Comment: I was about to mention that the 'Stars and Bars' method could have something to do with this. It actually makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Thanks, never knew the name for it!

Comment: Could you be more clear about the m's and n's though? I assume M is the digit and n is the increment?

Comment: Ok... Guess what? Your answer is absolutely right. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let the numbers be $a, b, c, d, e$.

What can you say about $a, b+1, c+, d+3, e+4$?

In particular, can you apply the Star and Bars method?